# How to get root layout in Xamarin using android?

Tags: c#, android, android-activity, xamarin

I`m using Xamarin for Android.
I know that i can assign an Id to the root layout and get it via this code :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/Root"
```

and in C# use :

```
var mLayout = (LinearLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.Root);
```

What i need is a method that could get the root layout without needing the ID. something like this:

```
var mLayout = GetRootLayout();
```

Answer (score 7):

In your activity just call `Window.DecorView.FindViewById (Android.Resource.Id.Content)`.

Comment: thanks, but i can not  use 'Android.Resource.Id.Content' or any id

Comment: Why? This is a special built-in id. You don't need to assign it to your view.

Comment: i am using mvvmcross and the view is loading dynamically, so i do not know witch view is loading... and in this state i need to access the root layout ...

Comment: That's ok. Again, `Android.Resource.Id.Content` is not your view's id. It's a universal id used to get view's content.

Comment: It doesn't matter which id is assigned to your view you still can use this code.

Comment: if you want to add view to the mainview :
 var mainView=(ViewGroup) MainActivity.Current.Window.DecorView.FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content);
 mainView.AddView(addyourview);